# Class location for User32 in JNA 4.1.0

Tags: java, eclipse, jna

I have read about [using native Window handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662956/handle-external-windows-using-java) in Java. I have [downloaded the JNA 4.1.0 JAR file](https://github.com/twall/jna#download) and added to the Eclipse Java Build Path.

However, when I type `User32` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, Eclipse doesn't give suggestions for an import.

What I have tried: I have created my [own User32 class like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962086/java-jna-findwindow-error-looking-up-function-findwindow-the-specified-pr).

However, I doubt that this is the correct way of doing it. Maybe I'm too optimistic, but I expect it to be easier... :-)

Comment: I think you want `com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32`

Comment: Have you included the jna-platform jar? I see a User32 class there.

Comment: @TJ- Stupid me: I downloaded JNA Platform it but only added JNA. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, I forgot to add `jna-platform.jar` to the Java Build Path.